# Cleanup tar command

Tags: debian, files, directory, tar, rm

I did via SSH:

```
tar xvfz t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
```

instead of `gunzip`.

And now:

```
gsamaras:~/Desktop/Data$ ls
$_?????)  ???=         Klein  siftsmall         Sphere
???       gist         MNIST  siftsmall.tar.gz  t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
????      gist.tar.gz  sift   sift.tar.gz       train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
gsamaras:~/Desktop/Data$ rm ???
rm: cannot remove ‘???’: No such file or directory
```

Other weird-named elements were created, deleted them. What now? How to delete these leftovers?

---

Not sure which the inode number:

```
gsamaras:~/Desktop/Data$ ls -il
total 2899108
17311143 ---------- 1 gsamaras gsamaras          0 Jan  1  1970 $_?????)
17311158 ---------- 1 gsamaras gsamaras          0 Jan  1  1970 ???
17311150 ---------- 1 gsamaras gsamaras          0 Jan  1  1970 ????
17311148 ---------- 1 gsamaras gsamaras          0 Jan  1  1970 ???=
17311000 drwxr-xr-x 2 gsamaras gsamaras       4096 Dec 16  2009 gist
17310981 -rw-r--r-- 1 gsamaras gsamaras 2740172684 Dec  2 04:11 gist.tar.gz
17309401 drwxr-xr-x 5 gsamaras gsamaras       4096 Dec  1 19:19 Klein
17311043 drwxr-xr-x 2 gsamaras gsamaras       4096 Dec  3 22:41 MNIST
17310949 drwxr-xr-x 2 gsamaras gsamaras       4096 Dec 16  2009 sift
17317672 drwxr-xr-x 2 gsamaras gsamaras       4096 Dec 16  2009 siftsmall
17317670 -rw-r--r-- 1 gsamaras gsamaras    5305734 Dec  1 01:20 siftsmall.tar.gz
17310947 -rw-r--r-- 1 gsamaras gsamaras  168280445 Dec  2 03:16 sift.tar.gz
17312617 drwxr-xr-x 5 gsamaras gsamaras       4096 Dec  1 19:45 Sphere
17311145 -rw-r--r-- 1 gsamaras gsamaras    7840016 Jul 21  2000 t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
17311135 -rw-r--r-- 1 gsamaras gsamaras   47040016 Jul 21  2000 train-images-idx3-ubyte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is with find and inodes.

`ls -il` will list each file with it's inode number **in the leftmost column**.
`find . -inum <the inode number discovered by ls> -exec rm {} \;`
For example:
`find . -inum 17311143 -exec rm {} \;`

`find` will execute `rm` on the file identified by the inode number.

Repeat for each file. There's probably a way to automate this by parsing the filenames returned by `ls`, but for the small amount of files in your case, it's not worth the time.

Comment: @gsamaras just added a clarification in my answer - the inode number is the leftmost (1st) column - so the first file has inode number 17311143.